# Replying to an Apple Event in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, appleevents, nsappleeventmanager

I'm registering an Apple Event handler using NSAppleEventManager:

```
[[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager]
    setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:)
      forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
```

My handler method will, of course, receive the event and a reply event:

```
- (void) handleGetURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent {
    //Open this URL; reply if we can't
}
```

So, if I need to reply with an error, indicating that I failed in some way to open this URL, how should I use the `replyEvent` to do that?

Answer (score 8):

I have translated the following from the old-style C procedural API described in Apple's legacy document "Apple Events Programming Guide" to Cocoa:

```
if ([replyEvent descriptorType] != typeNull)
{
    [replyEvent setParamDescriptor:[NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithInt32:someStatusCode] forKeyword:keyErrorNumber];
    [replyEvent setParamDescriptor:[NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithString:someErrorString] forKeyword:keyErrorString];
}
```

[See "Returning Error Information" in the "Apple Events Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleEvents/responding_aepg/responding_aepg.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001449-CH206-CEGFGBBG) (in the Legacy library).

Comment: but how to send this reply back?

Comment: @jimwan: Cocoa automatically sends it back. It's handing you an object for you to fill in with details. (Actually, Cocoa is just serving as an in-between. The underlying Apple Event APIs provide the reply event object to Cocoa and automatically sends it back.)